# Run Broadcastreceiver for specified time

Tags: android, android-service, android-broadcast

I am new to android, I want to run a task only for a specific duration, how can I do this? 
I tried using broadcast receiver and `AlarmManager` but the broadcastreceiver continuously runs even after specified time.

```
long timetorun= calendarcurrent.getTimeInMillis() - calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
Phonecallreceiver.class); 
pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, c, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarm.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timetorun, pintent);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can stop it by canceling the alarm, using the same PendingIntent like the below:

```
Intent c = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Phonecallreceiver.class); 
pintent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, c, 0);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE); 
alarm .cancel(pintent);
```

Do not forget to make sure that the PendingIntent is not NULL.
Hope that I helped you.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the exact moment to call **alarm.cancel(pintent)**